# How to get the size of a page in KB?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to get the Size of the complete loaded page in KB like how it is shown in the browsers console.
I used:

```
 var res = performance.getEntriesByType('resource');
```

but here I do not get the complete site, only the resources like .css, .images not the page itself.

```
   var totalSizeTransfer = res.reduce((size, item) => {
    size += item.transferSize;
    return size;
  }, 0);
  console.log("total Size Transfer ist: ",totalSizeTransfer);
```

The above code doesn't help.
Any Idea?
If it is not possible in Javascript is there a PHP solution?

Comment: do you mean the size of the html file?

Comment: I think you mean the resource/transferred size. it's true?

Comment: I mean the size of all transfered files include the html-file.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have full access to network traffic. Hence, your script could not catch all the requests.